# How to get Option[T] field type on Android in 2.10.1?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

Code like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru, currentMirror => cm}
import ru._

def test[T:TypeTag](obj: T) {
  for (c <- typeOf[T].declarations; if c.annotations.exists(_.tpe =:= ru.typeOf[Message])) {
    val tpe = c.asClass.selfType
    for (m <- tpe.declarations.sorted) {
      println("Member type: " + m.typeSignature)
    }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  test(TestMessageDef)
}

object TestMessageDef {
  @Message
  case class A(d: Option[Long])
}
```

Message define:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Message {
}
```

On PC I can get right output:

```
Member type: Option[Long]
```

but on Android, I get an output is:

```
Member type: Option[java.lang.Object]
```

My question is:

1. Why same code output different result on PC and Android?
2. How to get right type like PC?

UPDATED:

Only Option[T], T is Int, Long, Byte and so on primitive type has this problem. If I used Option[java.lang.Long] it output as expect.

Answer (score 0):

Android is not 100% compatible with Java. What you are seeing is the result of either Java Reflection API differences, or annotations needed by Scala reflection API lost while translating to DalvikVM.